# How to get value from map object with descending top 1

Tags: apex, collection

```
Id IdValue;

Map<ID, Account> mapAccount = new Map<ID, Account>([SELECT Id, Date, Name FROM Account]);
for (ID idKey : mapAccount.keyset()) {
    IdValue = mapAccount.get(idKey).Id
    Account a = mapAccount.get(idKey);
    System.debug('IdValue:' + IdValue);
}
```

How do I get Id from mapAccount with top 1 desc by Date

```
ID, Date
1, 1/2/2020
2, 1/3/2020
3, 1/6/2020
4, 1/5/2020
```

In above the result for IdValue should be 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a map, you can't (at least not without iterating over all the elements and comparing dates). Maps and sets are unordered collections.

You want to store the result of the query in a List (which you can pass into the constructor of a map if you need a map later on in your code) and use `ORDER BY` in your query.

The idea is that the resulting list will have your target record at index 0 (from which you can then retrieve the Id). Much less work and fewer edge cases than trying to iterate through a collection to obtain the same result.

Comment: Please provide the sample for iterating over all the elements and comparing dates

Comment: @MaheshIndia I will not, one of the reasons being that you haven't showed any attempt to implement it yourself. Beyond that, I do not believe iterating is the appropriate approach.